# Build branch separately and merge into master on pull request

Tags: git, jenkins

Currently I have a Webhook from my Git platform to Jenkins such that every time a pull request is made, the master is built.

I would like:

1.Build the branch with the changes.

2.Merge the branch with master and build master.

In the project configuration, under "*Source Code Management*" and "*Branch Specifier*", I filled in:

```
master
```

In this case only the master branch is built, but not the one with changes.

When I leave the option blank, all the branches are built, instead of just the one with changes and master.

Comment: Are you using any git hosting solutions, i.e. GitLab?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket

Comment: To build a specified branch I usually add build parameters and use them in  PreStep like that:
`cd $WORKSPACE; git pull origin $BRANCH; git checkout $COMMIT_VERSION`

Comment: 1.How do you know that `$BRANCH` is the branch that the pull request uses? 2.How do you know which ` $COMMIT_VERSION` to check out?

Answer (score 0):

`Merge before build` functionality of [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) solves exactly this issue.

On your job leave the `Branch Specifier` blank. Then on `Additional Behaviours` choose `Merge before build` and set master as `Branch to merge to`, so your branch with the changes will be merged into master prior the build.

If you then want this merge to be pushed to your repository, choose on the `Post-Builds` the `Git Publisher` and configure it as you prefer.